# ¿Se puede "desborrar" una pregunta o una respuesta?

Tags: soporte

Hace poco redacté una pregunta y, al poco de publicarla, pensé que, entre otras cosas, era de mala calidad, bordeando el off-topic y decidí borrarla, para evitar al [elenco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EWup5K1) de revisores el ponerla on-hold o cerrarla.

Posteriormente he visto que, dentro de mi perfil, aparece en "
Deleted Recent Questions" y que puedo marcar una opción de "**undelete**" para desborrarla.

La pregunta (que seguramente figure en el help center pero no he sabido encontrar) es doble:

1. ¿Durante cuánto tiempo puede un usuario "desborrar" una pregunta suya? Es decir, ¿hay un plazo tras el que desaparece de "Deleted Recent Questions"?, y
2. ¿Quién más puede "desborrar" preguntas y respuestas? Supongo que es uno de los superpoderes de los moderadores, pero ¿lo pueden hacer usuarios "normales" con un cierto nivel de reputación?

Comment: esta pregunta es meta dentro del meta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. ¿Durante cuánto tiempo puede un usuario "desborrar" una pregunta suya? Es decir, ¿hay un plazo tras el que desaparece de "Deleted Recent Questions"?, y**

La sección *Deleted Recent Questions/Answers* muestra las publicaciones borradas que fueron publicadas en los últimos 60 días ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/209901))

**2. ¿Quién más puede "desborrar" preguntas y respuestas? Supongo que es uno de los superpoderes de los moderadores, pero ¿lo pueden hacer usuarios "normales" con un cierto nivel de reputación?**

Tal y como comentas, en la sección de ayuda esto está explicado, en concreto en la sección [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions):

> Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except developers, moderators, and users with over 2,000 reputation. Deleted questions will also always be visible to their authors, regardless of the author's reputation. However, deleted posts can be undeleted by casting undelete votes. Once a post has 3 undelete votes, it will no longer be deleted.

Es decir, los usuarios con el [privilegio de acceder a las herramientas de moderación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), juntamente con los moderadores y desarrolladores, pueden ver dichas publicaciones. Ese primer tipo de usuarios también puede votar para recuperar una publicación, algo que los moderadores también pueden hacer. En este último caso, y como todo lo relacionado con votos de este tipo, el de los moderadores es un voto definitivo (no se necesitan tres votos para conseguir recuperar la publicación).

---

Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, si algún día quieres que se recupere alguna de tus publicaciones, repórtalo con un *flag* y los moderadores lo analizaremos. Indica más o menos dónde estaba esa publicación y así la podremos localizar más fácilmente.

Comment: Creo que OP quiere que su post que quedó *deleted* ya no sea visible por ningún usuario.  ¿Qué se puede hacer en ese caso?  Se puede levantar un flag para que un moderador lo haga desvanecer completamente?

Comment: Parece que el OP preguntó lo que contesté, pues ha aceptado la respuesta. No, los moderadores no podemos _desvanecer_ una publicación completamente, eso solo pueden hacerlo los empleados.